# How do I match a string in a list to a word in a sentence?

Tags: c#

I have two lists and a sentence. I need find out which string in any of the lists matches with a word in the sentence. So far, I've been able to do this by splitting the sentence into an array of the words then looping through each list and comparing elements to the array elements. My code is very clumsy though. Is there a more efficient/better way? Here is the code without the nested loops inside the if statements.

```
List<string> browserList = new List<string>(new string[] { "Firefox", "Chrome", "Safari"});
List<string> mediaPlayerList = new List<string>(new string[] { "VLC", "WinAmp", "WMP" });

string sentence = "I use Firefox everyday";

if (browserList.Any(sentence.Contains))
{
   // return the matching string (browser's name)
}

else if (mediaPlayerList.Any(sentence.Contains))
{
   // return the matching string (media player's name)
}
```

Comment: I don't know the details, but that looks like a problem where you could/should use sets...

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, this does exactly what your current algorithm does (respects match order and returns a single value):

```
var match = browserList.Where(sentence.Contains).FirstOrDefault() ??
            mediaPlayerList.Where(sentence.Contains).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 6):

Returns an `IEnumerable<string>`

```
IEnumerable<string> ienBrowser = browserList.Where(x => sentence.Contains(x));

IEnumerable<string> ienmediaPlayer = mediaPlayerList.Where(x => sentence.Contains(x));
```

Return the value you need:

```
if (ienBrowser.Count() > 0)
{
   return ienBrowser.ToList();  // Take the first element or entire list if you like
}

else if (ienmediaPlayer.Count() > 0) 
{
   return ienmediaPlayer.ToList();  // Take the first element or entire list if you like
}
```

[image]

However your `if` - `else if` format will not work if the sentence has a browser as well as a Media player name in it.

Comment: al-Khwārizmī, thanks for pointing out the flaw in my if/else statements. I'll be using combination of al-Khwārizmī and presius' answers.